# Namespace module inside class: instance variable scope

Tags: ruby

I have a class like this. I have Commands defined as a module for internal name-spacing (since it responds to commands from the player and commands will be periodically added and removed). However, methods in Commands cannot see @environments. How do I fix this?

```
class Player
  attr_accessor :environment

  module Commands
    def self.look *args
      @environment.describe
    end

    def self.exit *args
      Kernel.exit(true)
    end

    def self.method_missing *args
      puts "What?"
    end
  end

  def respond arg
    cmd = arg.split(" ")
    Commands.send(cmd[0], cmd)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@environment` is an instance variable so it's accessed from an instance of Player. Adding `self` before a method makes it a class method (a static method in other languages) to make the code above work you could do:

```
class Player
  attr_accessor :environment

  def initialize
    self.extend Commands
  end

  module Commands
    def look *args
      puts @environment.describe
    end
  end

end

player = Player.new
Struct.new("Environment", :describe)
player.environment = Struct::Environment.new("foo")
puts player.look
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to maintain the ability to keep the Commands module in a separate namespace (which is how it is currently in the module)?

Comment: @JonathanHoward it is already in a separate namespace: `Player::Commands`. The top level methods are in `Player`. Though I don't see much value in using a module unless you plan on sharing it with another class, or at the very least moving it into its own source file.